# Creating a section that it's height is adjustable according to the background-image height

Tags: css, height

I have 3 sections that their parents is only the body, section 2 (menu) background in this case is larger than 100vh. Giving the height:auto; won't work, I would like to stretch the height of the section according to the background length ( auto ), I don't want to give it a specific value using ( px, vh, cm, ... etc). I'm pretty sure it's simple answer but I couldn't figure it out my self. Thank you

```css
html,body {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#Home {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-image: url(/images/Header.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;


}

#Menu {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
 width: 100vw;
 background-image: url(/images/Menu.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
}
```

```html
<html>

 <body>
  <section id="Home"></section>
  
  <section id="Menu"></section>
  
  <section id="Map"></section>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no way for an element to know the height of a background image. The simple solution is to use an <img>.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it did work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this is by **not using** the actual background property.

As @Mr Lister commented:

> There is no way for an element to know the height of a background
>   image.

However, you can use an img tag with the image you want as background inside your #menu section.
Then, create a container div with absolute positioning which will contain the content of your actual section.

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Home {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/8tcxHWh.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<section id="Home"></section>

<section id="Menu">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BF3ty6o.jpg">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>My content</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="Map"></section>
```